# Semantic tableau software

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, math-software

Is it possible to find software to perform semantic tableaus (as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) automatically?

Right now I am proofing it by hand.

Comment: Yes. You can perform semantic tableus with Latex http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/trees/

Comment: I meant software to do it automatically instead of doing it by hand. Sorry for the misunderstanding :-)

Comment: https://creativeandcritical.net/prooftools/comparison-of-proof-tree-software

Answer (score 4):

A number of tableau provers for modal logics at least can be found under
http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~schmidt/tools/

You might be interested in LotREC, Logics Workbench, Mettel (resp. its successor Mettel2) or the Tableau WorkBench. These are generic provers and can be used for many logics, but usually come with calculi for propositional logic (and others) predefined.